# Erro estranho na chamada de metodo da classe

Tags: php

Pessoal tenho uma classe simples com 2 metodos, eis o codigo:

```
namespace app\Services;


use App\Repositories\LogRepository;

class LogService
{

    protected $repository;


    public function __construct(LogRepository $repository){
        $this->repository=$repository;
    }

    public function cadastrar($dados){
        return 'ola2';
    }

    public function deletar($id=0)
    {
        return 'ola';
    }
}
```

E numa outra classe eu chamo esta classe:

```
namespace app\Classes;

use App\Repositories\LogRepository;
use app\Services\LogService;

class Log
{
    private static $repository;

    private static $service;

    public function __construct(LogRepository $repository, LogService $service)
    {
        self::$repository=$repository;
        self::$service=$service;
    }

    static function Gravar($tabela, $evento, $sql=null, $valoresAntigos, $valoresNovos){
        self::$service->deletar(1);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Quando eu executo me da o seguinte erro:

> FatalErrorException in Log.php line 29:
>   Call to a member function deletar() on null

O que estou esquecendo de fazer ou fazendo errado?
Obrigado

Comment: Acho que: você cria uma instância de $service no seu construtor da classe Log. Mas a função Gravar é estática. Portanto, o construtor não é executado. É só um chute, nunca usei PHP.

Comment: Tem como acertar isto? Pois eu preciso desta classe estática.

Comment: Para testar tente criar a instância na própria função gravar.

Answer (score 1):

Seu erro está em tentar executar uma propriedade que não existe `null`.

Métodos estáticos **não** executam o método construtor da classe, pois nada é instanciado. Veja [esse exemplo](http://3v4l.org/lDEWQ):

```
<?php

class teste{

    public function __construct(){

        echo "executando construtor\n";
    }

    public static function ola(){
        echo "Metodo estático\n";
    }

}

teste::ola();
```

O resultado será simplesmente:

> Método estático

Aconselho a não criar métodos estáticos se não entender muito bem seus conceitos e como utilizá-lo de forma correta.

Para utilizar a sua classe `Log` criar uma instancia da mesma é mais simples:

```
namespace app\Classes;

use App\Repositories\LogRepository;
use app\Services\LogService;

class Log
{
    private $repository;

    private $service;

    public function __construct(LogRepository $repository, LogService $service)
    {
        $this->repository=$repository;
        $this->service=$service;
    }

    public function Gravar($tabela, $evento, $sql=null, $valoresAntigos, $valoresNovos){
        $this->service->deletar(1);

        return true;
    }
}

// Uso
$repository = new App\Repositories\LogRepository;
$service = new app\Services\LogService\LogService;

// Insere as dependências
$log = new Log($repository, $service);

$log->gravar(...);
```